# How many different ways are there to concatenate two files line by line using Perl?

Tags: perl, concatenation

Suppose file1 looks like this:

```
bye bye
hello
thank you
```

And file2 looks like this:

```
chao
hola
gracias
```

The desired output is this:

```
bye bye chao
hello hola
thank you gracias
```

I myself have already come up with five different approaches to solve this problem. But I think there must be more ways, probably more concise and more elegant ways, and I hope I can learn more cool stuff :)

The following is what I have tried so far, based on what I've learnt from the many solutions of my previous problems. Also, I'm trying to sort of digest or internalize the knowledge I've acquired from the Llama book.

Code 1:

```
#!perl
use autodie;
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $file1,'<','c:/file1.txt';
open my $file2,'<','c:/file2.txt';

while(defined(my $line1 = <$file1>)
        and defined(my $line2 = <$file2>)){
    die "Files are different sizes!\n" unless eof(file1) == eof(file2);
    $line1 .= $line2;
    $line1 =~ s/\n/ /;
    print "$line1 \n";
}
```

Code 2:

```
#!perl
use autodie;
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $file1,'<','c:/file1.txt';
my @file1 = <$file1>;

open my $file2,'<','c:/file2.txt';
my @file2 =<$file2>;

for (my $n=0; $n<=$#file1; $n++) {
    $file1[$n] .=$file2[$n];
    $file1[$n]=~s/\n/ /;
    print $file1[$n];
}
```

Code 3:

```
#!perl
use autodie;
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $file1,'<','c:/file1.txt';
open my $file2,'<','c:/file2.txt';

my %hash;

while(defined(my $line1 = <$file1>)
      and defined(my $line2 = <$file2>)) {
  chomp $line1;
  chomp $line2;
  my ($key, $val) = ($line1,$line2);
  $hash{$key} = $val;
}
print map { "$_ $hash{$_}\n" } sort keys %hash;
```

Code 4:

```
#!perl
use autodie;
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $file1,'<','c:/file1.txt';
open my $file2,'<','c:/file2.txt';

while(defined(my $line1 = <$file1>)
      and defined(my $line2 = <$file2>)) {
  $line1 =~ s/(.+)/$1 $line2/;
  print $line1;
}
```

Code 5:

```
#!perl
use autodie;
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $file1,'<','c:/file1.txt';
my @file1 =<$file1>;

open my $file2,'<','c:/file2.txt';
my @file2 =<$file2>;

while ((@file1) && (@file2)){ 
    my $m = shift (@file1);
    chomp($m);

    my $n = shift (@file2);
    chomp($n);

    $m .=" ".$n;
    print "$m \n";
}
```

I have tried something like this:

```
foreach $file1 (@file2) && foreach $file2 (@file2) {...}
```

But Perl gave me a syntactic error warning. I was frustrated. But can we run two `foreach` loops simultaneously?

Thanks, as always, for any comments, suggestions and of course the generous code sharing :)

Comment: Didn't you post a nearly identical question recently?

Comment: In fact, this sounds like a poll type question with no one right answer so probably should be CW.

Comment: @Kinopiko, that question I asked a couple of days ago "How can I replace a column of one file with a column of another using Perl?" was more difficult than this one.

Comment: @Kinopiko, well, I suppose they do share some similaritities but they are different whatsoever.

Comment: @Sinan, I suppose for beginners, this poll type question will prove to be very useful.

Comment: Isn't it the Perl motto: there's more than one way to do it.?

Comment: @Mike the point is, there will be many correct answers posted and I do not think you can rightly choose one as **the** correct answer. No matter which answer you chose, there would be other answers that are equally valid and correct because they are just showing a different way of accomplishing the same thing. That's why we are going around slurping willy nilly: To provide variety. If the question asked for the **best** way to do it, then @FM's answer is the only one that passes muster. Therefore, either paraphrase the question or make it CW.

Comment: @Sinan, ahh, CW means Community Wiki. I took it as closed, sorry.

Comment: @Sinan, I would like to make it Community Wiki. Please show me how. Thanks.

Comment: @Mike Upvoted your question now. I hope this earns you a Nice Question badge.

Comment: This is Perl.  I always get the feeling that, if I can find only one way to do something, I should be submitting a bug report.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This works for any number of files:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my @handles = map { open my $h, '<', $_; $h } @ARGV;

while (@handles){
    @handles = grep { ! eof $_ } @handles;
    my @lines = map { my $v = <$_>; chomp $v; $v } @handles;
    print join(' ', @lines), "\n";
}

close $_ for @handles;
```

Comment: BTW, I find `my @handles = map { open my $h, '<', $_; $h } @ARGV;` preferable. You get rid of the `@files` array which you do not use elsewhere. I wish I could upvote your answer several times.

Comment: Looks like @ARGV = ("c:/f1.txt","c:/f2.txt"); is more concise than open my $file1,'<','c:/f1.txt'; open my $file2,'<','c:/f2.txt';

Comment: @Mike Here's another way to do it: `my %d; push @{$d{$ARGV}}, $_ while <>`. That will slurp all of the files into a hash of array references. Printing the output is similar to my answer, but instead of pruning the list of file handles as you go, you will want to delete hash keys as their lists become empty.

Answer (score 12):

The most elegant way doesn't involve `perl` at all:

```
paste -d' ' file1 file2
```

Comment: +1 Agreed, but I think the OP's purpose is to learn Perl by working such toy programs.

Comment: @mouviciel, this doesn't look like perl. but I agree it IS concise :)

Comment: I don't know perl enough to write a one-liner for that task. Maybe something based on the answer of SanHolo?

Comment: @mouviciel: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636755/how-many-different-ways-are-there-to-concatenate-two-files-line-by-line-using-per/1637438#1637438 And, please **don't use it**.

Comment: In Perl:  `system("paste -d' ' $file1 $file2")`

Answer (score 7):

If I were a golfing man, I could rewrite [@FM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636755/how-many-different-ways-are-there-to-concatenate-two-files-line-by-line-using-per/1636981#1636981) as:

```
($,,$\)=(' ',"\n");@_=@ARGV;open $_,$_ for @_;print
map{chomp($a=<$_>);$a} @_=grep{!eof $_} @_ while @_
```

which you might be able to turn into a one-liner but that is just evil. ;-)

Well, here it is, under 100 characters:

`C:\Temp> perl -le "$,=' ';@_=@ARGV;open $_,$_ for @_;print map{chomp($a =<$_>);$a} @_=grep{!eof $_ }@_ while @_" file1 file2`

If it is OK to slurp (and why the heck not — we ***are*** looking for different ways), I think I have discovered the path the insanity:

```
@_=@ARGV;chomp($x[$.-1]{$ARGV}=$_) && eof
and $.=0 while<>;print "@$_{@_}\n" for @x
```

`C:\Temp> perl -e "@_=@ARGV;chomp($x[$.-1]{$ARGV}=$_) && eof and $.=0 while<>;print qq{@$_{@_}\n} for @x" file1 file2`

Output:

```
bye bye chao
hello hola
thank you gracias
```

Comment: @Sinan :) Thanks alot!  This wicked one-liner works great: perl -le "$,=' ';@_=@ARGV;open $_,$_ for @_;print map{chomp($a =<$_>);$a} @_=grep{!eof $_ }@_ while @_" "c:/file1.txt" "c:/file2.txt".

Comment: @Sinan, this line code does not work: perl -e "@_=@ARGV;chomp $x[$.-1]{$ARGV}=$_ && eof and $.=0 while<>;print qq{@$_{@_}\n} for @x" "c:/f1.txt" "c:/f2.txt". It gives me something like "Can't modify scalar chomp in scalar assignment at -e line 1, near "eof and" Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: @Mike I needed parentheses around the chomp. Should be OK now.

Answer (score 2):

An easy one with minimal error checking:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;

open FILE1, '<file1.txt';
open FILE2, '<file2.txt';

while (defined(my $one = <FILE1>) or defined(my $twotemp = <FILE2>)){
    my $two = $twotemp ? $twotemp : <FILE2>;
    chomp $one if ($one);
    chomp $two if ($two);
    print ''.($one ? "$one " : '').($two ? $two : '')."\n";
}
```

And no, you can't run two loops simultaneous within the same thread, you'd have to `fork`, but that would not be guaranteed to run synchronously.

Comment: Without testing, I can recognize there is the ternary operator I was expecting. Ah, this is cool. I myself made several attemtps to use the ternary operator to do the job but with no luck. Thanks alot :)

Comment: Does not work if the input line is the number zero. Use `defined` in the conditional operators.

Comment: Yeah, Rob, true. (Ok, I said that it concatenates for every line of the first file, so this behavior would be somewhat correct ;) ).
But that's what I meant with minimal error checking - that there should be more error checking.

Comment: Edit: Ok, adjusted so that it now reads to the end of both files, no matter how long they are.

Comment: No, I mean if a line is the digit zero, "0", then your script will not include that character in the output. I'm not talking about nul characters or empty lines, just the plain old number character at the top of your keyboard. I'm also not talking about files of different lengths or about error-checking.

Comment: Oh, right, I see! Never ran into this problem, but you're obviously right. I should get used to using `defined()` from now on, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

An easier alternative to your **Code 5** which allows for an arbitrary number of lines and does not care if files have different numbers of lines (hat tip @FM):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use File::Slurp;
use List::AllUtils qw( each_arrayref );

my @lines = map [ read_file $_ ], @ARGV;

my $it = each_arrayref @lines;

while ( my @lines = grep { defined and chomp and length } $it->() ) {
    print join(' ', @lines), "\n";
}
```

And, without using any external modules:

```
#!perl
use autodie; use warnings; use strict;

my ($file1, $file2) = @ARGV;

open my $file1_h,'<', $file1;
my @file1 = grep { chomp; length } <$file1_h>;

open my $file2_h,'<', $file2;
my @file2 =  grep { chomp; length } <$file2_h>;

my $n_lines = @file1 > @file2 ? @file1 : @file2;

for my $i (0 .. $n_lines - 1) {
    my ($line1, $line2) = map {
        defined $_ ? $_ : ''
    } $file1[$i], $file2[$i];
    print $line1, ' ', $line2, "\n";
}
```

If you want to concatenate only the lines that appear in both files:

```
#!perl
use autodie; use warnings; use strict;

my ($file1, $file2) = @ARGV;

open my $file1_h,'<', $file1;
my @file1 = grep { chomp; length } <$file1_h>;

open my $file2_h,'<', $file2;
my @file2 =  grep { chomp; length } <$file2_h>;

my $n_lines = @file1 < @file2 ? @file1 : @file2;

for my $i (0 .. $n_lines - 1) {
    print $file1[$i], ' ', $file2[$i], "\n";
}
```

Comment: Tested failed. Perl says "Can't locate List/Allutils.pm in @INC". But I'll grab the module and test it again.

Comment: +1 for `read_file` and `each_array`. I thought about this approach too, but then noticed your answer at the last minute. A person could easily generalize this to handle any N of files as well.

Comment: @Sinan, thanks! Module installed and tested the code again. it works great but there's a pesky problem. Perl gives me an error saying "can't locate perl58.dll". of course it can't locate perl58.dll because I'm now running Perl 5.10.1. How can I get rid of this false alarm without downgrading my Perl?

Comment: @Mike That seems like a separate question onto itself but it seems to me like either there the `perl.exe` from the previous installation is still in your path or there is some kind of file association issue. What does `ftype Perl` say?

Comment: C:/ftype Perl gives me this: perl="C:\Perl\bin\perl.exe" "%1" %*

Comment: @Sinan, so for this itsybitsy job, we can use quite an impressive lot of Perl operators and functions. This is GOOD.

Comment: @Sinan, one thing, I think this line of code should be added to your code: @ARGV = ("c:/file1.txt","c:/file2.txt"); I suppose for beginners, @ARGV would be difficult. I learnt something about this stuff from hobbs' answer to my first question "How can I search multiple files for a string?". Before that, I knew nothing about it. But maybe for unix systems, things are quite different. I'm not sure.

Comment: @Mike how do you invoke your script? And, yes, there is variety, but I do not think any of the solutions other than @FM's should be used.

Comment: @Sinan, how do I invoke my script? well, I write my code using Windows text editor and save it as .pl file and then drag the file to the Window Commandline Console. Then it works.

Comment: @Sinan, or maybe it's not the right way to run the script? I'm really not sure.