# Is there a Perl substitute for the cut and paste shell commands?

Tags: perl, paste, cut

I saw once a quick and dirty Perl implementation for the cut and paste linux commands. It was something like
`perl 'print "$F1"' filename`
to substitute a cut -f1 filename command

Can someone tell me how was this Perl way? Specifically, I'm interested because this, unlike cut/paste, will work the same also in Windows environments.

Comment: You might want to consider installing cygwin, so you can have (most of) the command line tools that you're used to from linux. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### cut

```
perl -alpe'$_=$F[0]'
perl -alpe'$_="@F[1..3]"'
```

To give a custom input separator,

```
perl -F: -alpe'$_=$F[0]'
```

To change the output separator,

```
perl -F: -alpe'$"=":";$_="@F[1..3]"'
```

To `grep` while you're at it,

```
perl -alne'print$F[0]if/blah/'
```

#### paste

Not quite as easy.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
for (@ARGV ? @ARGV : qw(-)) {
    if ($_ eq '-') {push @files, *STDIN}
    else {open $files[@files], '<', $_}
}
while (grep defined, (@lines = map scalar <$_>, @files)) {
    chomp @lines;
    print join("\t", @lines), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you know about the [Perl Power Tools](http://www.metacpan.org/module/PerlPowerTools)? They are implementations of your favorite unix commands, but done in Perl. If you have Perl, you can have your favorite commands without acrobatics on the command line. PPT has both `cut` and `paste`.

Although many people pointed you to some `perl` switches, they forget to link to [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) which explains them all.

Comment: ++! The PPT are an amazing resource.  They can be very handy if you are on a win32 platform, and they demonstrate some interesting techniques.

Answer (score 1):

For cut: I think you are looking for the `perl -ane` solution (the `-e` executes the following code, the `-an` applies `@F = split (/\t/,$line)` to every line in the file).
So something like:

```
perl -ane 'print "$F[0]\t$F[1]\n"' file
```

which is identical to:

```
cut -f1,2 file
```

For paste, I'm not sure how you can do this, but I think the `perl -ane` can take multiple files as input.

Comment: Note that cut drops the newline from the final field but Perl doesn't.  The expression should probably be 'chomp(@F); print "$F[0]\t$F[1]\n"' to fix that.

Comment: `paste` is more work. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636755/how-many-different-ways-are-there-to-concatenate-two-files-line-by-line-using-per for several possible implementations

Answer (score 0):

Perl equivalent of cut -c1-2

perl -alne 'print substr($_,0,2)'