# How can I concatenate corresponding lines in two files in Perl?

Tags: perl, input

file1.txt

```
hello
tom
well
```

file2.txt

```
world
jerry
done
```

How to merge file1.txt with file2.txt; then create a new file - file3.txt

```
hello world
tom jerry
well done
```

thank you for reading and reply.

Attached the completed code which based on the answer.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(F1,"<","1.txt") or die "Cannot open file1:$!\n"; 
open(F2,"<","2.txt") or die "Cannot open file2:$!\n";
open (MYFILE, '>>3.txt');

while(<F1>){ 
  chomp; 
  chomp(my $f2=<F2>); 
  print MYFILE $_ . $f2 ."\n"; 
}
```

Comment: Does it have to be perl or can it be linux?   You could do $ paste file1.txt file2.txt

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636755/how-many-different-ways-are-there-to-concatenate-two-files-line-by-line-using-per/1636981#1636981

Comment: Perl and WinXP used. $ paste ? Is it a command from Linux?

Comment: Sorry - what is the question here.

Comment: @justintime, I attached the code to my post based on ghostdog74's answer. Thanks you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if Perl is not a must, you can just use `paste` on *nix. If you are on Windows, you can also use `paste`. Just download from [GNU win32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)

```
$ paste file1 file2
```

else, in Perl

```
open(F1,"<","file1") or die "Cannot open file1:$!\n";
open(F2,"<","file2") or die "Cannot open file2:$!\n";
while(<F1>){
  chomp;
  chomp($f2=<F2>);
  print $_ . $f2 ."\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anyone should give a full answer for this.

Just open both files, then loop through both at the same time and write out to a new file.

If you don't know how to read and write files in perl, here is a tutorial:

http://perl.about.com/od/perltutorials/a/readwritefiles.htm

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial. I completed the script.