# How to open/join more than one file (depending on user input) and then use 2 files simultaneously

Tags: perl

EDIT: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I have edited a few things, to hopefully actually request what I want.

I was wondering if there was a way to open/join two or more files to run the rest of the program on.

For example, my directory has these files:

`taggedchpt1_1.txt`, `parsedchpt1_1.txt`, `taggedchpt1_2.txt`, `parsedchpt1_2.txt` etc...

The program must call a tagged and parsed simultaneously. I want to run the program on both of chpt1_1 and chpt1_2, preferably joined together in one .txt file, unless it would be very slow to do so. For instance run what would be accomplished having two files:

`taggedchpt1_1_and_chpt1_2` and `parsedchpt1_1_and_chpt1_2`

Can this be done through Perl? Or should I just combine the text files myself(or automate that process, making chpt1.txt which would include chpt1_1, chpt1_2, chpt1_3 etc...)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => "all";
print "Please type in the chapter and section NUMBERS in the form chp#_sec#:\n"; ##So the user inputs 31_3, for example
chomp (my $chapter_and_section = "chpt".<>);
print "Please type in the search word:\n";
chomp (my $search_key = <>);

open(my $tag_corpus, '<', "tagged${chapter_and_section}.txt") or die $!;
open(my $parse_corpus, '<', "parsed${chapter_and_section}.txt") or die $!;
```

For the rest of the program to work, I need to be able to have:

```
my @sentences = <$tag_corpus>; ##right now this is one file, I want to make it more
my @typeddependencies = <$parse_corpus>; ##same as above
```

**EDIT2**:  Really sorry about the misunderstanding. In the program, after the steps shown, I do 2 for loops. Reading through the lines of the tagged and parsed.

What I want is to accomplish this with more files from the same directory, without having to re-input the next files. (ie. I can run taggedchpt31_1.txt and parsedchpt31_1.txt...... I want to run taggedchpt31 and parsedchpt31 - which includes ~chpt31_1, ~chpt31_2, etc...)

Ultimately, it would be best if I joined all the tagged files and all the parsed files that have a common chapter (in the end still requiring only two files I want to run) but not have to save the joined file to the directory... Now that I put it into words, I think I should just save files that include all the sections.

Sorry and Thanks for all your time! Look at FMc's breakdown of my question for more help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247116/open-multiple-files-in-perl

Comment: By the way, I'm struggling so much in using an answer probably because I don't even know what a filehandle is yet... gotta get reading!

Comment: Perhaps natatime is required?

Comment: In your code, `$tag_corpus` is a file handle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could iterate over the file names, opening and reading each one in turn. Or you could produce an iterator that knows how to read lines from sequence of files.

```
sub files_reader {
    # Takes a list of file names and returns a closure that
    # will yield lines from those files.
    my @handles = map { open(my $h, '<', $_) or die $!; $h } @_;
    return sub {
        shift @handles while @handles and eof $handles[0];
        return unless @handles;
        return readline $handles[0];
    }
}

my $reader = files_reader('foo.txt', 'bar.txt', 'quux.txt');

while (my $line = $reader->()) {
    print $line;
}
```

Or you could use Perl's built-in iterator that can do the same thing:

```
local @ARGV = ('foo.txt', 'bar.txt', 'quux.txt');
while (my $line = <>) {
    print $line;
}
```

**Edit in response to follow-up questions:**

Perhaps it would help to break your problem down into smaller sub-tasks. As I understand it, you have three steps.

- Step 1 is to get some input from the user -- perhaps a directory name, or maybe a couple of file name patterns (`taggedchpt` and `parsedchpt`).
- Step 2 is for the program to find all of the relevant file names. For this task, `glob()` or `readdir()`might be useful. There are many questions on StackOverflow related to such issues. You'll end up with two lists of file names, one for the tagged files and one for the parsed files.
- Step 3 is to process the lines across all of the files in each of the two sets. Most of the answers you have received, including mine, will help you with this step.

Comment: @mu is too short On Chapter 8! :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the effort, seems a little advanced, so I will have to understand it.

Comment: @FMc: Could natatime be used with this, so that I can call 2 files at once? (ie. One parsed and one tagged), or can this be implemented directly?

Comment: @Jon I'm not sure I understand what you would like to do. Perhaps your goal is to read lines from two files at once, in parallel with each other: line 1 from both files, line 2 from both files, line 3 ... etc? That's certainly doable. If so, this question might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636755.

Comment: @FMc: Thanks a lot, the link was very interesting, it would have been very helpful earlier... check out the EDIT2 at the bottom of the question for details.

Comment: @Jon See the edited answer. Perhaps you should take a shot at Steps 1 and 2. If you get stuck, ask another question on StackOverflow. Hope that helps you think through the problem.

Comment: @FMc: Thanks a lot for all your help, you broke my own question down better than I could... My addition would be Step 1:user inputs chapter number, I automatically need parsed and tagged. THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there... this is a bit more efficient than discrete opens on each file...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => "all";
print "Please type in the chapter and section NUMBERS in the for chp#_sec#:\n";
chomp (my $chapter_and_section = "chpt".<>);
print "Please type in the search word:\n";
chomp (my $search_key = <>);

open(FH, '>output.txt') or die $!;   # Open an output file for writing
foreach ("tagged${chapter_and_section}.txt", "parsed${chapter_and_section}.txt") {
    open FILE, "<$_" or die $!;      # Read a filename (from the array)
    foreach (<FILE>) {
       $_ =~ s/THIS/THAT/g;   # Regex replace each line in the open file (use 
                              #     whatever you like instead of "THIS" &
                              #     "THAT"
       print FH $_;           # Write to the output file
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you leave out the open(my $parse_corpus... on purpose?  Thanks for the answer, I'll see if I can implement it.

Comment: @Jon, I did it intentionally... the `foreach` iterates through the array of file names and opens each one in series... writing the output of replacements (didn't know what you wanted), to a filename called `output.txt`.  Actually I left a line in there that could have been deleted.  Thanks for catching that

Comment: Umm, can I still use this to open both tagged and parsed simultaneously? Or do I just use two foreach loops, one for taggedchpt...  and one for parsedchpt...?
and then use the final two lines in my edited question? Thanks!

Comment: @Jon, it won't matter whether you have one or two files open at once if your perl program is single-threaded (as it is in your post).  If you want to process simultaneously, you will need to spawn threads for each file to be processed.  This is way more complicated than you probably need.  The foreach loop opens one file at a time and mangles the lines according to the contents of the regexp

Comment: @Mike Pennington: Sorry for my lack of understanding, but I do need both $tag_corpus and $parse_corpus simultaneously to use my program, can your answer do this? Thanks for your time

Comment: @Jon, I wrote this when the requirement for simultaneous access to both data sets wasn't as clear.  I can rewrite when I get off work today

Answer (score 3):

No one has mentioned the [`@ARGV`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlvar#ARGV) hack yet? Ok, here it is.

```
{
    local @ARGV = ('taggedchpt1_1.txt', 'parsedchpt1_1.txt', 'taggedchpt1_2.txt',  
                   'parsedchpt1_2.txt');
    while (<ARGV>) {
       s/THIS/THAT/;
       print FH $_;
    }
}
```

`ARGV` is a special filehandle that iterates through all the filenames in `@ARGV`, closing a file and opening the next one as necessary. Normally `@ARGV` contains the command-line arguments that you passed to `perl`, but you can set it to anything you want.

Comment: So if I leave the local out, and just type in, say tagged*.txt at the command line, would it give me @ARGV = all the taggedchpt's?

Comment: Also, using the `ARGV` handle explicitly is optional. The empty angled-bracket operator call `<>` means the same thing as `<ARGV>`.