# Add a new column to the file

Tags: awk, addition

How can I add a new column to a file using awk?

original.file

```
F1 F2 F3 ..F10
```

add F11 to original.file

```
F1 F2 F3 ..F10 F11
```

Comment: Where does F11 come from? Is it computed from F1..F10 or is it stored in another file?

Comment: how is it stored in another file? each field per line? or also a field from a CSV, or something like that? Is there any mapping relation between the two files? better give us examples, original.file, "another.file" and your expected output.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1636755/45249. My answer there is to use `paste` instead of `awk` but other answers may be useful as well.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try:

```
awk 'BEGIN{getline to_add < "f3"}{print $0,to_add}' f
```

Reads the column to add from file "f3" and saves it in the variable to_add. After that it adds the column to each line of file f.

HTH Chris

Comment: This adds the first line of f3 to each column for me.  Should it be
    awk '{getline to_add < "f3"; print $0,to_add}' f
instead?

Answer (score 33):

`awk '{print $0, "F11"}' original.file`

Comment: Or even `awk '$0=$0"F11"' original.file`

Comment: `awk -v OFS=x '{print $0, "F11"}'` if you want to change the output field separator (x)

Answer (score 24):

If you want to add a column to a file, you can do the following.

***remark:** We assume that the field separator `FS` equals to the string `"fs"`. You can replace this by anything, or if you just use <blanks> as field separator, you can remove the `BEGIN{FS=OFS="fs"}` part in any of the following solutions.*

**add a column at the beginning:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="fs"}{print value OFS $0}' file
```

**add a column at the end:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="fs"}{print $0 OFS value}' file
```

**add a column before column `n`:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="fs"}{$n = value OFS $n}1' file
```

**add column after column `n`:**

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="fs"}{$n = $n OFS value}1' file
```

**add a column before each of column `n1` < `n2` < ... < `nm`:** (start at the back)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="fs"; split("n1,n2,n3,...,nm",a,",")}
     {for(i=m;i>0;--i) $(a[i]) = value OFS $(a[i])}1' file
```

or for different values

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="fs"; split("n1,n2,n3,...,nm",a,","); split("value1,value2,...,valuem",v,",")}
     {for(i=m;i>0;--i) $(a[i]) = v[i] OFS $(a[i])}1' file
```

**add a column after each of column `n1` < `n2` < ... < `nm`:** (start at the back)

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="fs"; split("n1,n2,n3,...,nm",a,",")}
     {for(i=m;i>0;--i) $(a[i]) = $(a[i]) OFS value}1' file
```

or for different values

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="fs"; split("n1,n2,n3,...,nm",a,","); split("value1,value2,...,valuem",v,",")}
     {for(i=m;i>0;--i) $(a[i]) = $(a[i]) OFS v[i]}1' file
```

Comment: Oh great. very helpful. Just wondering where does the 1 come from in 'add a column after/before column n' and what's the meaning ?

Comment: @applequist 1 is the default condition which executes the default action which is `print $0`. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/63891/273492

Answer (score 0):

If you data is tabulated, this is the only thing worked for me:

```
awk '{print $0 "\tVALUE"}' file
```