# add column of 1's to tab-delimited file

Tags: awk

Can't find a solution, even though thousands of variations of this question have been asked.

I want to add a column of 1's to a tab-delimited file using awk or sed.

The file will have about 20 million lines, so something efficient would be nice.

turn this:

```
a   b   c
r   j   k
i   t   w
```

into this:

```
a   b   c   1
r   j   k   1
i   t   w   1
```

Comment: It's very surprising that you couldn't find an answer to this. I just googled the text "add a column to a file in unix" and the first couple of results contained several correct answers. Took far less time that typing this response.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add a new column to the file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551991/add-a-new-column-to-the-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you used `awk -F'\t'` instead of just `awk`:

```
{
    print $0 FS 1;
}
```

If you didn't use the -F option, replace `FS 1` with `"\t1"`.

Answer (score 3):

One simple way. Modify Input and Output field separators to a tab. The `NF` variable keeps last column, so increment for a new one, assign the `1` number and print:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" } { $(NF+1) = 1; print $0 }' infile
```

It yields:

```
a   b   c   1
r   j   k   1
i   t   w   1
```

Answer (score 3):

Code for [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
sed 's/$/&\t1/' file
```