# Using awk to append columns on a file

Tags: bash, awk

I have columns of data arriving from standard output (in my case a call to mysql), and I  would like to append at each loop the column in a file. How can I do?

```
Standard output:

 a1
 a2
....
 an
```

Saving in a file called table.dat:

```
table.dat:

 a1
 a2
....
 an
```

Then another output is produced:

```
Further standard output:

 b1
 b2
....
 bn
```

Appending to table.dat:

```
table.dat:

 a1   b1
 a2   b2
.... ....
 an   bn
```

...and so on. I can use paste, but I need three steps:

```
 line producing standard output > tmpfile;
 paste prevfile tmpfile > table
 mv table prevfile;
```

Is there a faster way, maybe by using awk?

This solution:
[Add a new column to the file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551991/add-a-new-column-to-the-file)
produces an empty table.

Comment: You can use `paste tablefile <(program)` to skip one temp file. If you have `sponge`, you can add `| sponge tablefile` to do the replacement in-place, otherwise you just need to use a temporary file and rename every iteration.

Comment: `[mysql call] | paste table - | sponge table` is exactly what I needed, thaks! Incredible this "`sponge`" in the `moreutils` debian package: I never heard about it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use paste like this by reading from stdin:

```
paste <(command1) <(command2)
```

e.g.

```
paste <(cat f1) <(cat f2)
```

instead of:

```
paste f1 f2
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to clarify some details in the case where the two streams given, don't have the same number of elements. Result with `paste` [as proposed by anubhava](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19796940/2900196) :

```
[ ~]$ cat t1.txt 
a1
a2
a3
[ ~]$ cat t2.txt 
b1
b2

[ ~]$ paste t1.txt t2.txt 
a1  b1
a2  b2
a3
```

Otherwise, with Bash just for fun :

```
[ ~]$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash

f1=t1.txt
f2=t2.txt

getNumberOfRows(){
    wc -l "$1"|cut -d" " -f1
}

s1=$(getNumberOfRows "$f1")
s2=$(getNumberOfRows "$f2")
[[ $s1 -le $s2 ]] && min="$s1" || min="$s2"

i=1
while read; do
    echo "$REPLY $(sed -n ${i}p $f2)"
   (( i++ ))
   [[ $i -ge $min ]] && break
done < "$f1"

[ ~]$ ./test.sh 
a1 b1
a2 b2
[ ~]$
```

In this example you could see that we don't display additional lines if a file is larger than the other.

Of course you could change files by command outputs in either `paste` or with this script ;)

Using `paste` :

```
paste <(COMMAND1) <(COMMAND2)
```

Using the script : see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606864/ffmpeg-in-a-bash-pipe/19607361#19607361) to see how to read a command output in a loop.

Comment: For a pure bash solution: `while read -u 4 a && read -u 5 b; do echo "$a $b"; done 4< file1 5< file2` is much more efficient than your repeated calls to `sed`. Enjoy!